# show div base on specific input text in multiple strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery question...So this is simple find the value if match from keyup show the button. But I want to ask for 2 questions to improve this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ktX/98/)

```
$("#test").keyup(function () {
    $("#yeah").css("display", this.value == "test" ? "block" : "none");
});
```

Where im stuck is:

Type `test` = good

type `test here` = nothing

I want to keep the display no matter how the string is place as long as its placed it will not go away

So Ex: `I want to do some tests` - will show

And the other question is how do you do multiple strings? like if i want to show it on `test` and something like `test2`?

Comment: Use `indexOf` or a regular expression to check if `test` is anywhere in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```js
$("#test").keyup(function() {
  $("#yeah").toggle(/test|something/.test(this.value));
});
```

```css
#yeah {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
<div id="yeah">
  Yeah!
</div>
```

This regexp matches anything with `test` or `something` in it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer for your both questions.

```
  $('input[name=amount]').keyup(function() {
      var testStr = $(this).val();
      var testStr2 = 'test';
      var testStr3 = 'texts';


  if (testStr.indexOf(testStr2) != -1 || testStr.indexOf(testStr3) != -1 )
    $('#yeah').show();
  else
    $('#yeah').hide();
  });
```

Comment: thanks man i would like to check you off too but gave it to the other. But thanks!